# The Logic of Differentiation under An Integral Sign

Tags: statistics, logic

I have been self-studying predicate logic in order to better understand the language of theorems. Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference (2nd Edition)* gives the following theorem stating the conditions under which a derivative of an integral is equal to the integral of a partial derivative, after evaluation at $\theta_0$ in both cases:

Suppose $f(x,\theta)$ is differentiable at $\theta=\theta_0$, that is,
$$\lim_{\delta\to0} \frac{f(x,\theta_0+\delta)
- f(x,\theta_0)}{\delta}\ = 
 \left. {\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}}f(x,\theta)
 \right|_{\theta=\theta_0}
$$
exists for every x, and there exists a function $g(x,\theta_0)$ and a constant $\delta_0>0$ such that
$$
(i)\;\Biggl|\frac{f(x,\theta_0+\delta)-f(x,\theta_0)}{\delta}\Biggl| \leq g(x,\theta_0),\;for\,all\;x\;and\;|\delta| \leq \delta_0,\
$$
$$
and\;(ii)\;\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,\theta_0)dx<\infty.
$$
Then
$$
\left. \frac{d}{d\theta} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,\theta)dx
\right|_{\theta=\theta_0}=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Biggl[
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f(x,\theta)
\right|_{\theta=\theta_0}
\Biggl]dx.
$$
Many functions, however, are differentiable at all $\theta$. In this case, condition (i) can be replaced by another condition that often proves easier to verify. By an application of the mean value theorem, it follows that, for fixed $x$ and $\theta_0$, and $|\delta| \leq \delta_0$,
$$
\frac{f(x,\theta_0+\delta)-f(x,\theta_0)}{\delta} =
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f(x,\theta)
\right|_{\theta=\theta_0+\delta^*(x)}
$$
for some number $\delta^*(x)$, where $|\delta^*(x)| \leq \delta_0$. Therefore, condition (i) will be satisfied if we find a $g(x,\theta)$ that satisfies condition (ii) and 
$$
\Biggl|\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f(x,\theta)
\right|_{\theta=\theta^\prime}\Biggl|
\
\leq g(x,\theta)\;for\;all\;\theta^\prime\;such\;that\;|\theta^\prime-\theta| \leq \delta_0.
$$

I'm having trouble expressing this in formal notation, particularly condition (i) and the final equation that replaces (i) for functions differentiable at all \theta. Maybe this can't be expressed by first-order logic, but I'm curious about the order of the existential and universal quantifiers for the variables in these two equations (e.g. for the last equation is there some different constant $\delta_0$ for each $x$, or does the same $\delta_0$ exist for all $x$? Was there a reason x wasn't explicitly quantified?).

Comment: Glueing all together, we have something like this : $\forall x \ \exists g(x, \theta) \ \exists \delta_0 > 0 \ \forall \theta' \ [ ( | \theta' - \theta | \le \delta_0) \to ( | \ldots | \le g(x, \theta)) ]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: That does not work. First-order logic by itself has no capability of quantifying over function-symbols, which is needed here. We need either higher-order logic or reification as in some set theory, in the latter the function application syntax is also not first-order syntax.

Comment: @user21820: Any advice on how to interpret this then? Does the final statement hold for a given value of x? What about theta? A value for theta isn't mentioned anywhere... Just generally, this statement seems to be missing something, and I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @LumpyGrads: I'm merely commenting that first-order logic is not suitable for a clean translation of what you want, since it quantifies over all functions $f$. However, that's not answering your question here. What you need to know is that free variables are universally quantified (at the outermost level) by convention unless otherwise stated. And in calculus there is a bad tendency to treat functions as strings rather than functions. "$f(x,θ)$ is differentiable at $θ=θ_0$" should have been written as "$f$ is differentiable at $(x,θ_0)$ for every $x$".

Comment: @user21820 Actually it *does* work in first order logic, *if we're working in a first-order theory which can talk about functions*. This is a subtle point, but for example ZFC - a set theory - is a first-order theory, and the sentence Mauro writes (when translated appropriately and mind-bogglingly tediously into the language of set theory) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes of course I know that, which is why I said in my first comment: "We need either higher-order logic or reification as in some set theory, in the latter the function application syntax is also not first-order syntax."

Comment: All in all, I think @user21820 clarified the main thrust of my question when mentioning that the final mathematical statement is implicitly universally quantified at the outermost levels.

Comment: @LumpyGrads: Do you want me to post my comments as an answer?

Comment: @user21820 Sure, I'll mark it as the one I think is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, free variables are universally quantified (at the outermost level) unless otherwise stated. And in calculus there is a bad tendency to treat functions as strings rather than functions. "$f(x,θ)$ is differentiable at $θ=θ_0$" should have been written as "$f$ is differentiable at $(x,θ_0)$ for every $x$", and the whole thing should be understood to be a statement about every such function $f$.

As for whether $x$ or $δ_0$ is quantified first, the phrasing you quoted is ambiguous, but by default it means that some $δ_0$ works for all $x$, which I think is the case here. Note that it is usually stronger than just having some $δ_0$ for each $x$, which is why they had it as a second condition, as the first condition of differentiability does not guarantee that a single $δ_0$ works uniformly for all $x$.